# Program to search if a number is contained in a 3x3 array only finds the last number

Tags: c++, arrays

/*--- search.cpp -----------------------------------------------------
Program to read a 3 X 3 matrix of integers mat and an integer item,
and search mat to see if it contains item.
--------------------------------------------------------------------*/

So in this activity we made a program to search a if a number is contained in a 3x3 array.

If I put in `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` as the elements of the array,

the only number it finds is 9

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 3;               // Set matrix size
//typedef int Matrix[SIZE][SIZE];   // Define data type Matrix

bool matrixSearch(int mat[SIZE][SIZE], int n, int item);

int main()
{
    // Enter the matrix
    int mat[SIZE][SIZE];
    cout << "Enter the elements of the " << SIZE << " X " << SIZE 
        << " matrix rowwise:\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)

        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) 

            cin >> mat[i][j];

    // Search mat for various items
    int itemToFind;
    char response;
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter integer to search for: ";
        cin >> itemToFind;
        if (matrixSearch(mat, SIZE, itemToFind))
            cout << "item found\n";
        else
            cout << "item not found\n";
        cout << "\nMore items to search for (Y or N)? ";
        cin >> response;
    }
    while (response == 'Y' || response == 'y');
}


bool matrixSearch(int mat[SIZE][SIZE], int n, int item) {
    bool found;  
    int col, row;

    for (row = 0; row <n; row++)
        for (col = 0; col < n; col++)  
            if (mat[row][col] == item) {
                found = true;
            }
            else
                found = false;
    return found;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You set `found` to false if an item is not a match:

```
    for (col = 0; col < n; col++)  
      if (mat[row][col] == item)  // if match, set found = true
        found = true;
      else
        found = false;           // otherwise false
```

So suppose you are searching for `item = 4` and the array is `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`. It will find `4` correctly and set found to `true`. But then the next element will be `5` and since it is not a match, `found` will be set to `false`.

To fix simply return from your function when the item is a match:

```
bool matrixSearch(int mat[SIZE][SIZE], int n, int item)
{
    int col, row;
    for (row = 0; row <n; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < n; col++) {
            if (mat[row][col] == item)
               return true;             //end function and return true
        }
    }
    return false;   //we got here, that means item was not found, return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because, the loop is not breaking, once the item is `found`. The loop continues to search for the item and changes `found` to be `false` again, unless it's the last item.

```
bool matrixSearch(int mat[SIZE][SIZE], int n, int item) {

   bool found = false; //initialize here 
   int col, row;

   for (row = 0; row < n && !found; row++)
     for (col = 0; col < n; col++)

       if (mat[row][col] == item) {
         found = true; // once found, break the loop
         break;
       }

   return found;
 }
```

Comment: I believe using `break` inside a `for` loop is deceiving and should always be avoided. The header of the for loop announces "this loop is going to run for all values of row and col from 0 to n-1" but then it stops before having tried all those values. So the header is lying to the reader. Instead, you could replace the condition with `row < n && !found` which clearly states "only run while not found".

Comment: Additionally, `break` only breaks the inner loop, not the outer loop. So I'm guessing you deceived yourself!

Comment: Absolutely! Edited the answer

Comment: Another approach (and the one I prefer) is to `return true;` when the value is found. At the end of the function, just `return false;`. Yes, some folks prefer a single exit. That can lead to state flags and confusion.